# How to fully map Windows keys on Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, karabiner

I have the latest iMac. I plug in ordinary Windows style keyboard (which I used when I worked on Windows PC).

I'm aware of the Karabiner tool. Is there a complete rule-set that enable me to feel absolutely comfortable (like on Windows) while working with iMac? So I want to just import rule-set, and all my Windows-keyboard experience back to iMac.

Comment: You really really don't want to do that. Just learn the difference. Your proposed method will fight you all the way.

Comment: I'd second what @Tetsujin said. The differences are minimal and learning the native shortcuts will be far more rewarding than fighting throughout.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have to work on both windows and mac machines

Comment: So do I, every day for 25 years. Learn the paradigm shift. It will be best in the long run.

Comment: seconded. Been using both for years and years, it is best to learn the native keyboard. It's a bit clumsy at first and you will always make occasional mistakes (CTRL-C on a Mac, etc.) But remapping everything to be PC-Identical is asking for trouble.

Comment: If there are particular aspects of using a pc keyboard which are bothering you, give specifics and someone can probably help. Some WIndows "keyboard experiences", like typing alt plus a decimal code to get a special character, are impossible on a Mac.